# In emacs, how to match a regexp at the end of the buffer

Tags: regex, emacs

In a text buffer I want to check whether a file ends with the string "`abc`" followed only by zero to two linefeeds (and then delete this ending characters).

So I need something like `looking-at-backwards` or I want to match at the end of the file (not the end of the line). What's an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the link to Xah Lee's write-up about `\'` help any?  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_regex_begin_end_line_string.html

Comment: @lawlist Good tip to use `\'`! I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`looking-back` is the function you are looking for to match backwards

Use the general postifx operator to 
[\{m,n\}](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html) to match up to 2 newlines:

```lisp
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (when (looking-back "^abc\n\\{,2\\}")
    (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))
```

Comment: The doc-string for `end-of-buffer` states (in part):  "*This function is for interactive use only; in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-max))` instead.*"  And, the doc-string for `beginning-of-buffer` states (in part):  "*This function is for interactive use only; in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-min))` instead.*"  Inasmuch as people who read this answer in the future may tend to copy and perpetuate the usage of `end-of-buffer` in a programmatic manner, please consider modifying your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe does not call for what is usually called a regexp *search* in Emacs.  It calls for matching a regexp at the end of the buffer (eob).  I've edited your question title and text accordingly.

For that, you just move to the end of the buffer temporarily and use `looking-back` to check for a regexp match.

```el
(defun delete-abc-SPC-<-3-newlines ()
  "Delete `abc ' followed by up to 2 newlines at eob."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ends-w-<-3-newlines  nil))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (setq ends-w-<-3-newlines  (looking-back "abc \n?\n?\n?")))
    (when ends-w-<-3-newlines
      (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))))
```

If you want the buffer not to be considered newly modified then use this:

```el
(defun delete-abc-SPC-<-3-newlines ()
  "Delete `abc ' followed by up to 2 newlines at eob."
  (interactive)
  (let ((ends-w-<-3-newlines  nil)
        (mod-buf              (buffer-modified-p)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (setq ends-w-<-3-newlines  (looking-back "abc \n?\n?\n?")))
    (when ends-w-<-3-newlines
      (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
    (set-buffer-modified-p  mod-buf)))
```

Comment: Sort of what I asked for, but I do think @hoelzel's answer is quite a bit more concise.

Comment: (1) It is more concise because it does not bother to define a command (as well as because of other things mentioned here). (2) It does not include `SPC` after `abc`, which is not what you asked for. (3) It mistakenly uses `end-of-buffer` (see `C-h f` for that: "**Don't use this command in Lisp programs! `(goto-char (point-max))` is faster.**"). (4) It mistakenly uses `save-restriction` instead of `save-excursion` (and there is no need for `save-restriction` here). (5) It does not restore the buffer-modification state. (6) It does not address your confusion over search vs regexp matching.

Comment: Some of your points are very valid and thanks for pointing out the issues with the other code. @hoetzel did address them. Overall I prefer the less detailed answer. - If you want to discuss this further we should move over to the discussion channels, I guess.